# How do I create a slash command in discord using discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to create a slash command for my discord bot, but I don't know how to execute code when the command is exuted

The code I want to use will send a message to a different channel (Args: Message)

Here is the code I want to use

```
const channel = client.channels.cache.find(c => c.id == "834457788846833734")
channel.send(Message)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to listen for an event `interactionCreate` or `INTERACTION_CREATE`. See the code below, haven't tested anything, hope it works.

For discord.js v12:

```js
client.ws.on("INTERACTION_CREATE", (interaction) => {
    // Access command properties
    const commandId = interaction.data.id;
    const commandName = interaction.data.name;

    // Do your stuff
    const channel = client.channels.cache.find(c => c.id == "834457788846833734");
    channel.send("your message goes here");

    // Reply to an interaction
    client.api.interactions(interaction.id, interaction.token).callback.post({
        data: {
            type: 4,
            data: {
                content: "Reply message"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

For discord.js v13:

```js
client.on("interactionCreate", (interaction) => {
    if (interaction.isCommand()) {
        // Access command properties
        const commandId = interaction.commandId;
        const commandName = interaction.commandName;

        // Do your stuff
        const channel = client.channels.cache.find(c => c.id == "834457788846833734")
        channel.send("your message goes here");

        // Reply to an interaction
        interaction.reply("Reply message");
    }
});
```